# How can i save base64 to image file on cordova / ionic or upload to server?

Tags: javascript, image, cordova, base64, ionic-framework

I write cordova application using ionic framework. My goal is to receive image from the gallery and send it to the server as base64 string. But when I do so server says that request is too large and denies it. I’m kinda stuck at this moment.

What is correct way to send images to a server?

Is there any way to send it as multipart?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/94e7fded-7162-445e-8ceb-97a2140866a9/entry/upload_a_picture_using_phonegap_on_android8?lang=en

Comment: You can upload file with the help of http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file-transfer

Comment: otherwise you can call third party plugin based on requirment(like protocol).

Comment: Vishal Singh, i am use ngCordova file transfer. But i don`t understand how can upload base64 as file on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imageResizer - helped me to save base64 image.